# Google Spreadsheet, Checking the name of the sheet with a cell in a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with 3 sheets.

In the first sheet I have a resume of the two other sheet. This sheet has a column "C" where the name of the sheet corresponding to the resume is written.

Now I want a script that checks the name of the sheets and color the corresponding cell in column "C" into red if the name matches with the one in column "C".

I have written this code but doesn't seem to be working!

```
function myFunction() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var columnC = sheet.getRange (1, 3, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
var Cvalues = columnC.getValues();
var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
var allSheetNames = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < allSheets.length; i++)
{
  allSheetNames.push(allSheets[i].getName());
}

for (var j=0 ; j < Cvalues.length; j++)
{
if (Cvalues[j][0] == allSheets) {
  sheet.getRange( j, 1, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('red');}
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here:

```
if (Cvalues[j][0] == allSheets) {
```

Your `allSheets` is an array, so the value in `Cvalues[j][0]` can never be equal to it. What you probably want it to determine if `Cvalues[j][0]` appears anywhere in `allSheets`. Here's how you'd do that:

```
if (allSheets.indexOf(Cvalues[j][0]) !== -1) {
  ...
```